# How should I tweak the options in NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to obtain an accurate result from a difficult-to-integrate function and I've thrown in the kitchen sink worth of options in `NIntegrate`.  I think I'm close but I'm wondering if any of the options appear to be out of sync with the others.  I've also used `Rationalize` to remove some of the warnings.  Going from `WorkingPrecision=200` to `WorkingPrecision=300` makes a sizeable difference.  The result changes from `0.14724925610708290271` to `0.13739254580887418686`.  Are there any other suggestions to be more likely to have an accurate result?

```
  f[n_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{ra, rb, rka1, x},
  ra = Rationalize[a, 0.000000001];
  rb = Rationalize[b, 0.000000001];
  N[-Log[n] - ra Log[rb] + LogGamma[ra] -
    (1/n) Sum[Log[Abs[StirlingS1[n, k]]] +
       Log[
        NIntegrate[
         x^Rationalize[k + a - 1, 0.00000001] Exp[-rb x] Gamma[x]/
           Gamma[x + n], {x, 0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 100, 
         PrecisionGoal -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 300, 
         MaxRecursion -> 50, 
         Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]], {k,
        n}], 20]]
(* Evaluate function *)
N[f[305, 0.4154876, 0.0008710662], 10]

(* Out[2] 0.13739254580887418686 *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my take on it.  The integrals themselves are very small (one is around `10^-626`).  Coincidentally that's around `10^(-2 n)`, so I thought to multiply by that.  I haven't tested it for other values of `n`, but it works for `n = 305` as in the example.  If you have many different such integrals to do, you might spend some time analyzing this factor.

```
Options[f] = Options[NIntegrate];
f[n_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{ra, rb, rka1, x},
  rka1 = SetPrecision[k + a - 1, OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]];
  ra = SetPrecision[a, OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]];
  rb = SetPrecision[b, OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]];
  N[-Log[n] - ra Log[rb] + LogGamma[ra] -
     (1/n) Sum[
      Log[Abs[StirlingS1[n, k]]] + 
       Log[NIntegrate[10^(2 n) x^rka1 Exp[-rb x] Gamma[x]/Gamma[x + n],
         {x, 0, Infinity}, opts]] -
       Log[10^(2 n)],
      {k, n}], OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]]]
```

As you can see, the results are stable:

```
f[305, 0.4154876, 0.0008710662, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]
f[305, 0.4154876, 0.0008710662, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]
f[305, 0.4154876, 0.0008710662, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]
(*
  0.138332
  0.1383322373624130769
  0.13833223736241573880082453510
*)
```

They're also close to your second result.  For some reason, which I haven't explored, the very small integrals are contributing to numerical error.  There's nothing else in the integral (e.g. oscillatory behavior) that would suggest these integral would be difficult to evaluate.  It looks like increasing the working precision beyond 300 would work, but I believe this way is easier and faster.

*Addendum*

For what it's worth, here is the exact value of the `NIntegrate`, but it's taking forever to evaluate `f`....

```
i0[n_, rka1_, rb_] := 
  1/(n - 2)!  rb^(1 - rka1) Gamma[rka1] *
    Sum[E^(rb*k) (-1)^(k - 1) Binomial[n - 2, k - 1] ExpIntegralE[rka1, k*rb],
        {k, n - 1}] ;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Being able to use a lower `WorkingPrecision` really speeds things up!

Answer (score 4):

You lose precision using `Rationalize[#, 0.000000001]&` rather than `Rationalize[#, 0]&` For example,

```
Rationalize[#, 0.000000001] & /@ {0.4154876, 0.0008710662}
```

> {2731/6573, 51/58549}

```
% // N // InputForm
```

> {0.4154876007911152, 0.0008710652615757741}

Which is not the original input; whereas,

```
Rationalize[#, 0] & /@ {0.4154876, 0.0008710662}
```

> {1038719/2500000, 1969022/2260473429}

```
% // N // InputForm
```

> {0.4154876, 0.0008710662}

```
f[n_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {ra, rb, rka1, x},
  rka1 = Rationalize[k + a - 1, 0];
  ra = Rationalize[a, 0];
  rb = Rationalize[b, 0];
  N[-Log[n] - ra Log[rb] + 
    LogGamma[ra] - (1/n) Sum[
      Log[Abs[StirlingS1[n, k]]] + 
       Log[NIntegrate[
         x^rka1 Exp[-rb x] Gamma[x]/Gamma[x + n], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
         AccuracyGoal -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 300, 
         MaxRecursion -> 50, 
         Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]], {k, n}], 
   20]]

f[305, 0.4154876, 0.0008710662]
```

> 0.13739259268852118740

Comment: Thanks! While I do read the documentation, someday I'll actually comprehend the documentation.  That now makes sense about using `0` to always get a rational number.